# How can I resize a partition managed by LVM?

Tags: partitioning, centos, gparted, lvm

I have a fresh CentOS install on my machine and I would like to make space on the drive available in order to install Arch Linux.

Unfortunately, LVM is new to me and doesn't appear to work well with gParted (on my Ubuntu 9.0 LiveCD, anyways).  It always seems to treat the LVM as some unknown filesystem.  I tried to use the 'lvm' utility on the LiveCD in order to resize the partition down, but I ended up somehow corrupting my filesystem (hence the fresh CentOS install).

I haven't been able to find any documentation on LVM that makes much sense to me as a *nix n00b.  Is there anywhere I can find some helpful documentation on LVM as well as a clear step by step on how to successfully resize a partition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [LVM HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) is the place to go for most things. As for reducing, remember that you need to reduce the innermost layer first, then work outwards. This means `resize2fs` (or the proper counterpart for the filesystem in use), then `lvreduce`.